# how to make list display multiple items per row depending on media query

Tags: reactjs

I am building my website which displays various lists which are stored as JSON objects.

Initially the list displays all items, then I have a search box with can be used to filter out different items.

I want my list to display as many as 4 json objects per line all the way down to only one object per line. depending on media queries.

I thought by simply resizing my list item divs that it would automatically fit extra divs onto each row until the max width of the container div was used then it would render the next object on the next line etc. however this has not worked and it continues to just display one object below another and won't display more then one object per line.

list layout:

```
export function Athlete(postDetail){
  return(
    <div className='Athletes'>
    <p>Name: {postDetail.Name}</p>
    <p>Town: {postDetail.Town}</p>
    <p>State: {postDetail.State} </p>
    <p>PostCode: {postDetail.PostCode}</p>
    <img src={postDetail.Image} className='photo' alt='athlete photo'/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

list layout css:

```
.Athletes{
  width:15%;
  height: 15%;
  justify-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: grey;
  border-style:groove;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

list function:

```
export function AthleteList({athletes}) {
      let athl = athletes.map((athlete, i) => {
        return <Athlete key = {athlete.ID} {...athlete}/>
      });
         return <div>{athl}</div>
      }
```

search box function:

```
export function AthleteSearchBox({value, handleInput}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={handleInput} value={value} type ='text' className = 
'searchBox'/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

originally I had the height and width of .Athletes{} as 55% so that it could only render one image per row as two would take up over 100% of the container div. But now that I want to render more I reduced them to 15% but the outcome is still the same one below the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div` by default is a `block` element meaning that sibling divs will stack by default.

If you wish to for them to be in a row, you can do the following:

```
export function AthleteList({athletes}) {
      let athl = athletes.map((athlete, i) => {
        return <Athlete key = {athlete.ID} {...athlete}/>
      });
         return <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">{athl}</div>
      }
```

`display: flex;` will put all the direct children in a row, while `flex-wrap: wrap;` wrap will ensure that items are placed in a new row when there is not enough space on a given row.

Comment: Thanks for your help it’s not working I must have an issue somewhere else. I will keep working on it until I get it sorted.

Comment: Sorry, I initially put it in the right place, see updated answer.

Comment: that still wont work nothing seems to change it that I have tried, when I decrease the size and get rid of all margins etc. The objects just render on the left hand side but still one under the other. thanks again

Comment: sorted it out. the issue was I had another div which was overriding the container div and making it ignore the styling you told me to use @Jacobdo.